# How to insert into a table with NOW() in pdo_mysql

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I am trying to use mysql NOW() function when I insert a record with Zend_Db but it is not working it seems.
//$transaction is a very normal Zend_Db_Table object

```
$transaction->insert(array('date_created' => 'NOW()')); //inserted 0000-00-00 00:00:00

$transaction->insert(array('date_created' => '2010-12-12 12:12:12')); //inserted 2010-12-12 12:12:12
```

I am pretty sure I could do it using

```
$transaction->query()
```

But was wondering what was wrong with my first approach. Also NOW() does work on the server when in phpmyadmin.

All this on ubuntu server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()')` instead of the string `NOW()`

Comment: Works! I was expecting it to work without using this but oh well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Without using this, how would you expect PHP to distinguish between a function call `NOW()` and a string that contains `'NOW()'`?

Comment: What if I do it exactly this way but I've got the string "NOW()" instead of a date in my View?? Why my `Zend_Db_Expr()` doesn't seems to work? THANKS